# Why exe file created with pyinstaller have issues with writing to files?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

In my python code I open a txt file to add some numbers read from Tkinter entry fields (called here numeriaccount). 
Then I call another function which reads this file and perform other actions:

```
    with open("accounts.txt", "w+") as f: # I open the txt file

        for i in range(len(self.numeriaccount)):  # I scan through the entry fields

            t = self.numeriaccount[i].get().strip()

            # I write the entry field data into the txt file
            if (i == len(self.numeriaccount) - 1 ): 
                f.write( t ) 
            else:
                f.write( t + "\n" )

    self.check_something() # this function reads the same file and performs other actions
```

The Problem is only with the exe file generated by pyinstaller, NOT if I run normally with python filename.py:

the file is not updated fine and the second function reads wrong characters and throws an exception. If I open the text file after launching this script via python filename.py I can see the file content with the numbers, but if I open the same file after launching filename.exe the text file is empty. 
Another strange thing is that it happens not on all PC i tested the files with.

Any idea of what could lead to this issue? thanks

EDIT: as requested I add more info and a traceback:

[image]

In blue, the content of the 5 entry fields, which should be what is saved into the text file. 
In the red pointed line, you see what is read from the self.check_something() function after opening the file and doing a split on the \n. 
As you can see instead of the 2 numbers and empty strings there is nothing, and then the last element is completely wrong.

Another info: when the system is halted on this exception, if I open the file I see nothing. when I close this app, the file content is updated fine, the 2 numbers are saved in the file and nothing is wrong. that's what's driving me mad... that's why it can't be a folder problem or wrong file..

And again, it works fine on some pc, and some others don't...

Comment: I'd start by using a fully-qualified path to your file to flush out working-directory differences. Also, maybe, log `os.getcwd()`. And yes, **always** include an exception *in the question*; don't just say "throws an exception" and make us guess what it is.

Comment: Can you provide full traceback please?

Comment: Beyond that, syscall-tracing tools are the next place to go; you haven't told us what operating system you're on, but if you track which files are created then you'll see if, f/e, it's opening a different `accounts.txt` than you want it to. On Linux that would be `sysdig` or `strace -f`; on Windows, [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), etc.

Comment: Are you aware of **Current Working Directory**? Add a `print(os.getcwd())` to see which your app is using.